# R - install rJava on RStudio - Amazon Cloud

Tags: r, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, package, rstudio

I am using R on AWS EC2:
AMI ID

RStudio-0.98.501_R-3.0.3_ubuntu-13.10-64bit (ami-f06131a2)

and I cannot install rJava.

As far as I know I do not have access to Ubuntu commandline to run this code:
    sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava

Here is the error. Is there anything I can do inside RStudio?

```
Installing package into ‘/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rJava_0.9-6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 567515 bytes (554 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 554 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘rJava’ ...
** package ‘rJava’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
configure: checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 supports static inline...
yes
checking whether setjmp.h is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking whether sigsetjmp is declared... yes
checking whether siglongjmp is declared... yes
checking Java support in R... present:
interpreter : '/usr/bin/java'
archiver    : '/usr/bin/jar'
compiler    : '/usr/bin/javac'
header prep.: '/usr/bin/javah'
cpp flags   : '-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include'
java libs   : '-L/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm'
checking whether Java run-time works... 
./configure: line 3729: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
no
configure: error: Java interpreter '/usr/bin/java' does not work
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/rJava’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpYSTRK3/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: She has the JDK, look at the configure output.

Comment: maybe need to set JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here. I should use PUTTY terminal to connect to the instance commandline:
http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava` ?

Is there a reason you cannot use the distribution's rJava package?

Comment: I do not have access to Ubuntu. I log into rstudio and logout.

Comment: That is a little unusual. But if it is really the case, then you may have to accept that you may be unable to install certain packages.

Comment: watch this video  on 2:52. I login and logout like that: http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/video_guide.html

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems installing a package that depended on rJava. Dirk's suggestion worked like a charm on a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10