# How to install 'rJava' on RStudio Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, rjava, rstudio-server

I run Ubuntu (on an Apple Mac) and Linux (on Dell). When I started with 'R' I found it a challenge to install packages with rJava dependencies - also having trouble installing rJava.

I finally found an amazing way to install rJava on Ubuntu/Linux (credit to Hanna Rudakouskaya @ https://github.com/hannarud/r-best-practices/wiki/Installing-RJava-(Ubuntu) - for this amazing breakdown. I now have rJava installed and and rJava installed on my RStudio desktop. All packages are installed and running brilliantly.

I have recently migrated to RStudio Server to get more grunt, which is amazing. Even though rJava is successfully installed on each machine, I am having the same issues with with installing the rJava package in RStudio Server.

The only related question on StackOverflow is ([R - install rJava on RStudio - Amazon Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749448/r-install-rjava-on-rstudio-amazon-cloud)) but the response seems to indicate for Windows rather than Linux/Ubuntu

Has anyone experienced similar challenges? I would be so grateful for any advice.